# React native Firebase setDoc async await not updating firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, async-await

[The lines that are confusing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UDsAI.png)
Basically I need to do a very simple stuff, store some data into firestore. The two lines being commented out are not updating successfully on a slower device, but working fine on a fast device. I resolved this issue by wrapping up the setDoc() function with another function. With this approach, it works on both devices. I am very confused about why the wrapper function is necessary

I did a lot of research online but did not find relevant issues.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Also see: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) and [Formatting text and code](https://overflow.tips/write-good-question/formatting-text-code)